# Http Request using java.net.* package

Tags: java, httprequest

I am firing API calls through java package java.net.*
But, for 400 and above Responses I am not getting the response body. So Not able to figure out why the call is failing.

Below snippet fires the call.

```
public static String sendPostRequest(String requestUrl, String payload, Map<String, String> requestProperties) {
        StringBuffer jsonString = new StringBuffer();
        try {
            URL url = new URL(requestUrl);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            Set<String> keys = requestProperties.keySet();
            for (String property : keys) {
                connection.setRequestProperty(property, requestProperties.get(property));
            }
            OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            writer.write(payload);
            writer.close();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                jsonString.append(line);
            }
            br.close();
            connection.disconnect();
            //  System.out.println("response  " + jsonString.toString());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Error for call " + requestUrl);
            log.error(e.getMessage());
        }
        return jsonString.toString();
    }
```

Is there any work around?

Answer (score 2):

For responses with status codes 400 and higher you need to use `connection.getErrorStream()`. Calling `connection.getOutputStream()` will throw an exception. You can use `connection.getResponseCode()` before calling `connection.getOutputStream()` or `connection.getErrorStream()` to determine the status, and therefore which of the two methods to use.